# Automation testing (selenium python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, pytest

this is the conftest.py file. And I think there is some issue in this code. when I call Webdriver through BASETEST class in test_login.py file then unable to get the webdriver element.

```
import pytest
import time
from FamepilotProject.Config.config import TestData
from selenium import webdriver
   

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def init_driver(request):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(TestData.CHROME_EXECUTABLE_PATH)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(TestData.APP_URL)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='ui teal animated button']").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='E-mail address']").send_keys(TestData.USER_NAME)
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Password']").send_keys(TestData.PASSWORD)
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='ui teal fluid button']").click()
    time.sleep(10)
    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

BaseTest.py

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("init_driver")
class BaseTest:
    pass
```

now my issue is in the load method when I type self.driver and press the full stop I don't get the autocomplete to show the webdriver methods eg get,find_elements which leads to my question how does this class know that driver is of type web driver?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code that will solve your issue.

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("init_driver")
class BaseTest:
    def test_title(self):
        assert "Verify Title" in self.driver.title
```